# Pop out some Views in Light and put Some Views in Shade XML Android

Tags: android, xml

I want to make view like this in the below XML

[*VIEW IMAGE*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7nK6.jpg)

When a user clicks editing mode, it will take some view to shade and pop some view to light.

Is it possible to do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#feca81"
    android:paddingTop="15dp">

    <View1
        android:id="@+id/shareIconInProfile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/favIconInProfile"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fullNameField"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/share_icon" />

    <View2
        android:id="@+id/locIconInProfile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/favIconInProfile"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fullNameField"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/loc_icon" />

    <View3
        android:id="@+id/badgeIconInProfile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/put_badge_icon_in_profile" />

    <View4
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <View5
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_bg"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my sample code to switch to editing mode

```
profileImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         //Do some stuff here which I dont know how to
        }
    });
```

Please Help me if you know how to
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please shows us what have you tried till now ?

Comment: add an overlay `View` with semi transparent background and control its visibility by calling `View#setVisibility`

Comment: @KishuDroid Please see the image in the question..

Comment: @pskink I have tried that but that doesnot make any difference. Transparent view doesnt appear while testing.. But it appears in xml Design View

Comment: not `"transparent"` but `"semi transparent"`, like `#88ff0000`

Comment: @pskink Yes I have tried that.. I have used #80000000 which should show  semi transparent black background.. which actually shows in xml view but does not show in app while testing

Comment: i dont see any reason why wouldn't it show on the emulator